# CSS center ul list inside a 100% width div

Tags: css, html-lists

I feel as if I have tried everything from `text-align center` to `margin:0 auto` with a position relative and width of 100%, but they didn't work, I am trying to center my UL inside the div...

Here is my code

```
<style type="text/css">

.header {
  height: 40px;
  background: #000;
  width: 100%;
}

.header ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.header li {
  float: left;
  line-height: 40px;
}

.header li a {
  color: #FFF;
  padding: 0 18px;
  height: 40px;
}

</style>
```

```
<div class="header">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Rates</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Reviews</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">FAQ</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: `<div class="header"><div class="menu"><ul><li>home</li></ul></div></div>`

Comment: Give the UL display:inline-block and margin:0 auto and see if that works. If not give it a set width with margin: 0 auto too.

Comment: for it to center it generally needs to know how wide it is. you might find margin 0 auto works then.

Answer (score 11):

This works without having to define a set width.

```
ul {
    display: table;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

If you want to get rid of the left-side padding, thus genuinely centering the list, add:

```
padding-left: 0;
```

Answer (score 4):

This should fix it for you.

```
ul {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

If that doesn't work for you then give the UL a set width i.e.

```
ul {
    width: 300px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: I tried this `.header ul {
 list-style-type:none;
 width: display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}` but didnt work